# activate a steam game for a third party user authenticated via openid

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

is it possible to activate a Steam game for a third party user using steam API? by using OpenID or something else?

The idea is that I have a list of game keys and want to programmatically add the games to a set of users.

Comment: The easiest way would likely be [Archi Steam Farm](https://github.com/JustArchiNET/ArchiSteamFarm/wiki/Background-games-redeemer), but you'd have to split the keys into one file per bot and it seems like they'd have to be run in a manual queue. Should be possible to script, but I don't have a PC to test this theory.

Comment: Fine, but this tool would activate all keys into this single user, not across many users that have delegated access to my application.

Comment: Yes, you would have to create a different file full of keys and either attempt to automate the process or run each one at a time. If you're trying to give people access to your app you can [run a closed beta](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/store/testing) rather than activating keys on their accounts for them, which may raise a red flag.